# How to understand the crawling’s difference between site column and library’s column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I’m a freshman about share point. forgive me if i ask some silly questions.

1. Site column can be crawled automatically, right? so ows_XXXX(crawled property) will be generated so that we can search the files by using them in search box. So how about a library column? i think it can be indexed by setting. by it i can’t find and ows_XXX(crawled property). but it also can be searched in the search box! what’s the difference? how do they work?
2. i have some libraries. of course all of them have title columns. Is the title column a library column or site column? will it been crawled automatically?
3. Index and crawling, are they have any relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a site column contains any value, a crawled property and managed property will be created so you could search based on it, a column of a library will be mapped to a crawled property, if you need search based on the column, you need create managed property for it and do (full) crawl.

OOB title column is site column.

"The crawler makes requests for content and is in charge of determine which files should be processed. The indexer is responsible for building the index by processing the files returned by the crawler"